# impedance and resistance in phasors

Tags: impedance

[image]

Hi, so I'm a bit confused with this solution (though I'm not sure if it is correct). Why is the R in the solution 8 when the magnitude of the impedance is 10. Is this because the resistance is only the real part of the impedance? But why is the I equal to 10 in the equation not 10 cos(-37) when using P=I^2R? Last question is power dissipated equivalent to active power(real portion of apparent power)?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the R in the solution 8 when the magnitude of the impedance is 10.

The resistance \$R\$ is the real part of the impedance \$Z\$.

In your problem, \$R\$ is 8 because you were told the impedance is \$8+j6\$ and the real part of that is 8.

> But why is the I equal to 10 in the equation not 10 cos(-37) when using P=I^2R?

Because the \$R\$ term already contains the \$\cos(-37)\$ factor, since you could express it as \$R=Z\cos\phi\$.

The fundamental equation for real power is \$P_R =\Re{\lbrace VI^\star\rbrace}\$ where the superscript \$\star\$ indicates the complex conjugate.

From this you can obtain either their second equation \$P = VI\cos\phi\$, or, by substituting \$V=ZI\$,
$$P=\Re\lbrace (ZI)(I^\star)\rbrace$$
$$P=\Re\lbrace Z \rbrace\ II^\star$$
$$P= R\ \left|I\right|^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about it is that the real portion of the impedance - the resistance - is the power that is "lost" or dissipated as heat, which is the quantity the question is looking for.  The imaginary portion of the impedance - the reactance - is current that flows into the circuit to build up magnetic fields (in an inductor) or electric fields (in a capacitor).  You "get back" this current on the other half of the waveform when the field collapses and the energy gets converted back to electrical power.  This current still needs to be accounted for in wiring, component sizing, etc however.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks "What is the power dissipated in the circuit?" - The key word here is dissipated, this word indicates that they are after the real, true or active power (rather than VA which is apparent power or VARS which is the reactive power) that is the power (watts) actually used in the circuit in the resistive part of the load and the resistive part of the load is the real part of the impedance which is 8 Ohms. The reactive part of the load (j6) doesn't actually dissipate any power, it just stores it for a short time before returning it to the power source  (repetitively).

The current in the resistance is 10 (presumably Amps). It doesn't matter, as far as the resistance is concerned, that this current is lagging the input voltage by 37 degrees, it is still 10A which is flowing in the resistance. The voltage across the resistance will be in phase with the current through it. That is to say that the angle of the resistance is 0 degrees.